# The type 'x' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime...'

Tags: compiler-construction, .net-4.5.2

When I turned my project referencing to PCL assembly to .NET 4.5.2, I got compiler error: "The type 'System.Windows.Input.ICommand' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'."
There are many such questions, but no one is not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a reported bug: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/873446/project-targeting-4-5-2-fails-to-build-when-referencing-a-pcl.

I choose .NET 4.5.1 target framework and error gone.

Answer (score 0):

The System.Runtime dll file is distributed as part of Windows 8 SDK.

Here's the installation link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/hh852363.aspx